# Playing audio with controls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, core-audio

Is there any framework or set of classes that will allow me to play an audio file(mp3) with a small view displaying controls (slider, pause/play, etc)?
This image explains what I am talking about, it doesn't have to be exactly like that, but similar:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. You'll just have to create them yourself. Except for the volume bar, for that you can use a `MPVolumeView`.

You could use a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` but that occupies the entire screen and you wouldn't be able to modify it. If that's ok, then a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is your best bet.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController certainly does not occupy the entire screen since iOS 3.2 and its ability to add its view to any of your own views as a subview.

Comment: You're right. I meant `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. So does that mean the type of view I posted above is possible with MPMoviePlayerController ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `MPMoviePlayerController`, but using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` will look somewhat like this http://img209.imageshack.us/img209/8020/fotoyq.png